# Method to call a function in javascript in a particular way

Tags: javascript

I am kinda new to js and would appreciate some help to clarify one subject.
Basically i want to call some functions that i write like default javascript are called:

```
//declaring function
const splitAsExample = text => text.split('|')

//calling function
splitAsExample('Yesterday|Today|Tomorrow')
```

Instead of calling the function as mentioned above, i would like to know if it's possible to make a function that can be called like:

```
'Yesterday|Today|Tomorrow'.splitAsExample()

//and || or
'Yesterday|Today|Tomorrow'.splitAsExample
```

I learned js all by myself and didn't manage to find a specific name for this question to search up in google. :)
If you can clarify this topic for me it would be great, but if you could give me the name to search it up would be even better!

Comment: Add it to the prototype of String ```String.prototype.splitAsExample```

Comment: `'Yesterday|Today|Tomorrow'.splitAsExample()` would be possible but you would have to mess with the prototype of the builtin `String` object: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) function to `String`.

This allows [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) with a given object.

```js
String.prototype.splitAsExample = function () { return this.split('|'); };

console.log('Yesterday|Today|Tomorrow'.splitAsExample());
```

Comment: _"You could..."_ - But there's almost always a better way instead of modifying the prototype of a builtin object like `String`